# Unidad de medida de una CPU en DOCKERS?

Tags: json, docker

Estoy analizando un JSON en dockers.stats, del cual la estructura de CPU es la siguiente:

```
"cpu_stats":{
        "cpu_usage":{
            "total_usage":1523207123477,
            "percpu_usage":[1523207123477],
            "usage_in_kernelmode":629340000000,
            "usage_in_usermode":799260000000},
            "system_cpu_usage":11960316930000000,
            "online_cpus":1,
            "throttling_data":{
                "periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0
            }
        },
            "precpu_stats":{
                "cpu_usage":{
                    "total_usage":1523206502893,"percpu_usage":[1523206502893],
                    "usage_in_kernelmode":629340000000,"usage_in_usermode":799260000000
                },
                "system_cpu_usage":11960315940000000,
                "online_cpus":1,
                "throttling_data":{
                    "periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0
                    }
                },
```

Necesito saber qué medida tiene el uso de la CPU (bytes no es el caso), para poder realizar una conversión a un dato más preciso, y mostrarlo en una gráfica.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a cómo Moby Project realiza (en lenguaje [Go](https://golang.org)) el cálculo del porcentaje aquí: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/eb131c5383db8cac633919f82abad86c99bffbe5/cli/command/container/stats_helpers.go#L175

Comment: Vale, @OscarGarcia. Lo del porcentaje lo entiendo cómo hacen. Pero en el caso de total_usage, en qué lo está a medir?

Comment: Son el número de "ticks" de CPU en una centésima de segundo (también llamados *["user jiffies" -  mediawiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_(time))*): https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#cpu-metrics-cpuacctstat . Edito: Siento no darte una implementación del cálculo, sin saber en qué lenguaje estás desarrollando no puedo ser de mayor ayuda :(

Comment: De acuerdo. No tiene alguna fórmula de conversión hasta la fecha actual? Lo tengo que calcular en una BD Oracle.

Comment: Es una unidad independiente de la frecuencia tanto de los ticks como de refresco de la información, por eso se usa el porcentaje para representar el uso. Puedes consultar el número transcurrido en el sistema con: `grep ^jiffies /proc/timer_list`. En mi caso, con Ubuntu 12.04, tengo 250 por segundo. Así que el tiempo de cada "tick" es dependiente del sistema operativo, versión, configuración del núcleo, etc.

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia.